# to get the statistics of pageview, unique user, without any further info, ELK is enough?

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, elastic-stack

A full big-data stack may involve Hadoop, Hive, Hbase, Kafka, Elasticsearch , Logstash, Kibana and more.

If what i need is just pageview, unique user count, is ELK(Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) enough?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is good enough. Just (1) post data to elasticsearch directly using [index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) or Logstash; (2) query them out using [aggregation API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) or Kibana for visualization. It is a pretty easy and stable setup. You would even just use elasticsearch through APIs without Logstash and Kibana.